# Hard wood tree and Soft wood(shrubs) Vegetation Differentiaton

Tags: remote-sensing, erdas-imagine, envi, land-cover, forest-ecology

How I Differentiate Hard wood tree (like Mango, Sal) and Soft wood(shrubs like reed) Vegetation using Multispectral or Hyperspectral Image? I have TM, ETM, OLI, Hyperion, Aster Image and ERDAS 2011, ENVI 5.1, Arcmap 10.1. 
Is it possible to differentiate?

Comment: Are you primarily trying to differentiate between deciduous and conifer trees? Any of the sensors you described can be used to differentiate between these classes of vegetation.

Comment: no, this is not. I want to know if there is any methods to discriminate soft stem and hard stem vegetation?